# jQuery unbind events declared in scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I've got some object that **creates some event attached to document**. They are common events like mousemove, mousedown etc.

Then I want to make `$(document).unbind('mousemove')` and its ok but it may crash some events created by end user of plugin or cause **conflicts** with some external code.

Is it possible to **remove all events declared inside some scope** only?

Like:

```
$.fn.somePlugin = function() {
    //here begins our scope

    //declaring a lot of events

    //some stuff

    //remove events of this scope leaving other of same type untouched
}
```

Or is there any other way of managing groups of events?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [namespaced event](http://api.jquery.com/on/#event-names) handlers

Ex

```
$(el).on('click.myplugin', function(){...})//or any eventname.pluginname
```

then

```
$(el).off('click.myplugin')
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/nT9NT/)

Comment: will it wokr as normal click event via click.something?

Comment: @Kluska000 yes... it works as a normal event hanlder

Comment: Thats awesome, So bad I didnt know it earlier! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Pass a reference to the function to the `off` method.

From http://api.jquery.com/off/

```
var foo = function() {
  // Code to handle some kind of event
};

// ... Now foo will be called when paragraphs are clicked ...
$( "body" ).on( "click", "p", foo );

// ... Foo will no longer be called.
$( "body" ).off( "click", "p", foo );
```